# How to fix positions and keep them constant once assigned?

Tags: integer-programming, mixed-integer-programming

I am attempting to frame a problem based on the following assumptions:

There is a group of families $F$ of varying sizes, each owning a car, and requiring transportation for their daily needs, such as work, shopping, and school. In a small area, some families are interested in carpooling, but their schedules are unpredictable, varying each day and hour, making it impossible to prearrange rides on a daily or weekly basis. Therefore, I am looking to formulate a problem that involves a group of families with transportation needs, interested in sharing their rides with other families if their routes overlap. For example, a parent might drive to work and pick up a classmate of their child on the way to school. However, on other days, they may work from home and not require the same route. Given this uncertain scenario,  where the positions are not fixed but need to remain constant once assigned; how can I formulate this problem as an MILP?

Previously I though to have two Dynamic subset $D$ and $R$ from $F$. But based on the comments (thanks for that) I think this way of formulating is beeter.

Decision variables:

$x_{i,j,f} =1 \quad$   if family $f$ drives from $i$ to $j$

$y_{i,j,f,f'} =1 \quad$   if family $f'$ be driven by $f$ from $i$ to $j$

$z_{f} =1 \quad$ if family $f$ plays a roles of driver

$\hat z_{f}=1 \quad$ if family $f$ palys a role of rider

Constraints :

- a family could be either driver or be driven by other $z_{f}+ \hat z_{f} \le 1$
- every one should leaves their origin

  - For drivers:  $\sum_{j} x_{o_f,j,f} =1 \quad \forall f \quad$
  - and for those who are driven $\quad \sum_f \sum_{j} y_{o_f,j,f,f'} =1 \quad \forall f'$
- a family can drive if they assigned to  $x_{i,j,f} \le z_{f}$
- capacity should be controled  $\quad \sum_{f'} \sum_{j} y_{i,j,f,f'} \le M x_{i,j,f} \quad \forall f$
- flow constraint

  - for family who drive $\sum_{j} x_{i,j,f} = \sum_{k} x_{j,k,f}$
  - for family who are driven $\sum_{j} x_{i,j,f,f'} = \sum_{k} x_{j,k,f, f'}$

Now the question is how to use $\hat z_{f}$? Do I even need this?

Answer (score 1):

Why not try something like this
Let $p$ represent a ride/route/path for the day, then
$d_{f}^p + r_{f}^p \le 1 $ where $ d,r$ are binary variables that indicate if a family $f$ is playing role of driver $ d_{f}^p = 1$ or rider $ r_{f}^p = 1$ for route $p$.

Comment: Also, as soon as a family are assigned as being a rider, I should write a constraints satisfying their travel needs. Basically I don't know how to activate or deactivate a set of constraints related to routing riders and drivers family based upon their assigned role, or binary variables

Comment: If you make $D$ a subset whose membership is to be dynamically decided, then that itself will be another optimization variable. And having a variable like $x_{ij}^d=1$, you are anyway creating multidimensional variable, which means more variables. While separating driver & rider like $d_f$ or $ r_f$ will make it cleaner. Also complexity/size of a model doesn't increase with constraints, it increases with number of variables.

Comment: so if you separate driver/rider role as separate variables $ d, r$, you can control corresponding constraints simply using these variables for an assigned family. As I mentioned a family $f$ can be assigned either of the role as $ d_f + r_f \le 1$

Comment: I don't know what is the route/path the model should suggest a path, the only parameter we have is the home/office/school/ shop locations they want to visit. They should remain in their roles the whole day or once they came back to their car locations. So, a binary variables on path could work?

Comment: Ok in that case use destination location/node $v$ instead of p, as after all a family will not change role from start-destination, once assigned.

Comment: by separating roles as binary variables, why we couldn't use just one binary variables $d_f$ indicating if that family play a driver role, and all others are rider. Basically could we ignore $r_f$ altogether?

Comment: @linkho yes agreed. One more set of variables less. But then you have scenario where a family can neither be driver or rider- not travelling